# Is it discouraged to down-cast a returned instance to gain functionality that is not exposed via the returned class type?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

This is the basic scenario:
A method returns a class of type A, but after looking at the internal workings of the code it is found safe to assume that it actually returns B (a subclass of A). Is it then valid to do something like this? Or would you highly discourage it because it is accessing protected data (at least):

Assume that you do *not* maintain this code that implements the method as well. I.e, your software could ship with a different implementation of this (well established) method.

```
A returnedData = executeMethod();
if(returnedData instanceof B)
{
    ((B)returnedData).someFunctionNotExposedThroughAIsItProtected();
    //Use it as B, safe but non OOP and accessing protected functionality?
}else
    writeAFallBackOfSomeSort();
```

Comment: It's not accessing *protected* data. It's accessing *hidden* data, that can be unhidden through well-documented mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is the `if(returnedData instanceof B)`: if such a statement exist, it is proven that the returned object is a B (which in turn also includes A), so using B public method is safe.

In pure OOP sense this is not "elegant", but it is often the pragmatic way to go.
Think a while: a `Dog` is an `Animal`, but is unlikely that `Animal` has a do-nothing `bark` method, otherwise -for completeness- it must have all methods for all possible animals may have, thus making `Animal` a sort of "God Object" (a well known anti-pattern).

It is more pragmatic once you've got an `Animal`, ask it to `bark` only after you recognized it is a `Dog`. You can have then more `Dog` subclasses (representing different dog races) `bark`ing differently, but bark belongs to `Dogs`, not `Animal` in general.

The problem now becomes: is it correct to suppose an `Animal` could be a `Dog`? If you can check it, why not!

Use OOP as a technique where convenient, not as a religion to serve.

Consider also that the answer can change depending on the language used and on what feature it has around objects and the way it define what a "object" is. Where no runtime dispatch exist (or where runtime dispatch is single and you need multiple) this can be even a well established method.

Comment: While in the general case you should of course forgo artificial and subjective "elegance" in lieu of pragmatism, there are two quite specific constraints in this question: *"method returns a class of type A"* and *"you do not maintain this code that implements the method"*. Even if the language is dynamic and the "type specification" is just xDoc, IMHO it's usually **more** pragmatic to stick to what the API developer tells you you should expect, unless e.g. you are writing one-off code.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: Yes, this can be true. My concern is about "safety". Until you can check what the runtime type is, it is safe to cast. The day the return rintime-type will be another, you will not execute the specific code anymore. Where is this convenient or not depends on the context (an mainly in what you spent to write that specific code and what do you loose -in functionality- the day it will not be executed anymore. The "discouragement" comes from negative trade-off, not from a coding practice. Code written that way works and is perfectly maintainable: It is clear what it does.

Comment: I guess it boils down to whether we're talking about "safety" of the executed code in terms of semantics, or "safety" of the codebase not needed to be changed when the API's internal representation changes. You concentrated on the former, I on the latter, and both are valid.

Answer (score 2):

It most certainly is discouraged.

A method of an API declares a specific return type because that's what the API developer decided to declare. It creates a ***contract*** essentially saying "expect **this type** and **nothing else**". If the API developer didn't want to expose another type, (s)he probably had a good reason for that.

The internal implementation of the method should, in the general case, never concern you. The API developer can change it at any time, and in this case **you** are the one responsible for the consequences, not her/him.

Granted, your workaround is OK, as long as the sole contents of `writeAFallBackOfSomeSort()` **is not**

```
private void writeAFallBackOfSomeSort() {
    //TODO: I'll implement this later
}
```

.